# Parsing the JSON Object with variable quantity of data in Android efficiently

Tags: java, android, json, performance

I am looking into ways to parse a JSON object efficiently in Android.
I can make it work using `String` operations but that isn't very efficient as the number of values can increase very rapidly.

**Sample JSON Object**

```
{
  "device": "Hello",
  "sensor": "There",
  "data": {
    "1465324280": 214,
    "1465324312": 215,
    "1465324344": 214,
    .
    .
    .
    "1465324394": 216
  }
}
```

I can create a JSON object `MyJson` and print the `data` by:

```
System.out.println(myJson.optString("data"));
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "1465324280": 214,
    "1465324312": 215,
    "1465324344": 214,
    .
    .
    .
    "1465324394": 216
}
```

On this output String operations can be taxing if it's huge, so I would want a way to store all the `data` in a 2D array for computation later on.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Have you tried deserializing your JSON into a Java Object

Comment: I tried to use the gson library, but it nears the max memory usage we are targeting. :/

Comment: i really can't understand what you mean by saying `the max memory usage we are targeting`, shouldn't the server returns chunks of data instead of throwing everything at once? and by huge, how huge the data could be?

Comment: It could be like 5k values at max.
GSON to deserialize requires lots of additional processing and using that takes the app's memory footprint to a higher than desired value with lots of data.
I am trying to build an array of the data to populate a time series graph with this data.
Thanks